# Calculating gravity with inclometer?

Tags: gravity, simulations

How would one calculate the gravity vector for [X,Y,Z] by using an inclinometer which gives Pitch, Yaw and Roll.

A little explanation of the goal: I have a accelerometer I was planning to use to map movement. But as gravity being what it is, it affects everything.

So the Accelerometer reports [aX,aY,aZ] = a, and a contains actually two components gravity's [gX,gY,gZ] = g and movements [mX,mY,mZ] = m meaning that we have g+m=x so to do movement detection is more or less impossible unless I could keep the meter leveled at all times, and then i could remove the gravity component.

But since this is a moving system I thought that gyrometer could be used, but it has horrible drift and don't work. Next step is naturally to use a Inclometer and then calculate what gravity is supposed to be and subtract that.

The inclometer outputs like this in a [Pitch,Yaw,Roll] vector.
[image: inclometer decriptor]

I expect the calculated gravity [cX,cY,Cz]=c and that c - g ≈ 0 Making is useful to say movement accel m + g - c ≈ m